# How to print as pdf multiples word documents with vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, export

I have a list of names that I need to merge each of them in pre-set Word document and then export/print/save an individual "certificate" in a PDF format for each of them.

I put the code to change the Word document in a While and after changing it I call the function that I am calling "Imrpimir PDF". Here is the whole code:

```
While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista de Presença").Cells(i, 2) <> Empty
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista de Presença").Cells(i, 4) = "Presente" Then

        participante = UCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lista de Presença").Cells(i, 2))

        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wrdApp.Visible = True

        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Evento").Cells(1, 7).Text & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Evento").Cells(1, 2).Text & "\" & "Modelo.docx")

        With wrdDoc
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "#NOME"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection.Range = participante

            Imprime_PDF (participante)

            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
                If Not objWord Is Nothing Then
                    wrdApp.Quit False
                    Set wrdApp = Nothing
                End If
            Loop Until wrdApp Is Nothing
        End With

        Set wrdApp = Nothing
        Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

The function "Imprime_PDF" is:

```
Function Imprime_PDF(participante)
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Evento").Cells(1, 7).Text & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Evento").Cells(1, 2).Text & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Evento").Cells(1, 2).Text & " - Certificado de " & participante & ".pdf ", ExportFormat:= _
wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateWordBookmarks, _
BitmapMissingFonts:=True
End Function
```

Meantime, this code change all the Word documents, but it only saving as a pdf the first one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what happens if you delete `On Error Resume Next`? that line *hides* errors but they still occur. Also, does your lopp execute more than once? Also, you don't need to create a word Object every time. You can create one outside your loop,and then just open and close different Word files. and quit app after your loop.

Comment: Is `Sheets("Lista de Presença").Cells(i, 4) = "Presente"` for all the cases you need to be printed?  And try replacing of `Loop Until wrdApp Is Nothing` with `Loop While wrdApp Is Nothing`. Didn't your code stay in an infinit loop?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. However, now I am getting an error in ```If Not objWord Is Nothing Then```. It returs Erro 424 (object is required).

Comment: Yes, Foxfire And Burns And Burns. My loop happens more than once. For each Cells with "Presente" in it. How could I make the code just open and close different Word files instead of closing the app every time?

Comment: Take this code from the loop and use it only once of the end of your code: `wrdApp.Quit False`    
                    `Set wrdApp = Nothing`.